# reading the property in java from command line

Tags: java

How to read some property passed from command line like `-Dthread.count` I saw it, but I'm not sure how to read that one in java code

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
String value = System.getProperty("thread.count");
```

Answer (score 5):

Java has this documented:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Basically, you're reading in the value of a System Properties.  The link above gives you an example.

Comment: Sigh...if I had been notified there were answers, I would had posted.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`System.getProperty("thread.count");`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29)